# Passing arguments to a run() method of QThread

Tags: multithreading, qt

I've subclassed my Qthread so I can implement my code in `run()` method. I have to pass it some parameters,

I tried it like this, so what's wrong in here?

```
class QMyThread :
    public QThread
{
public:
    QMyThread();
    ~QMyThread(void);
    virtual void start(FILE *data, int sock, int bits);

protected:
    virtual void run(FILE *data, int sock, int bits);
};
```

run method;

```
void QMyThread::run(FILE *data, int sock, int bits)
{
//do stuff
}
```

start the thread:

```
QMyThread *thread;
thread->start(datafile, sockint, bitsint);
```

first it says the thread might not be initialized and then it crashes in the `start()` method with `SIGSEGV error`. Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't be subclassing the QThread class as this is no longer the recommended way of using QThread.

For more information http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qthread.html

To answer your question, couldn't you just make those parameters members of your class and assign their values through setters or its contructor?

Comment: ok, without subclassing the QThread how can I add parameters to the dowork() function? and how to get some values from the dowork function to the gui thread?

Comment: @SamuelNLP - you can pass the data to your worker object via the constructor or some initialization method.

Comment: I tried like this, `Worker *worker = new Worker(sock, bits);`

Comment: Maya Posch has a great article on QThread: [How To Really, Truly Use QThreads; The Full Explanation](http://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-really-truly-use-qthreads-the-full-explanation/). There is another article that's pretty good too: [You're doing it wrong...](http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2010/06/17/youre-doing-it-wrong/)

Comment: For those in recent years coming across this, here's an article that takes a very different view on this:
https://woboq.com/blog/qthread-you-were-not-doing-so-wrong.html
and the Qt documentation for QThread has been updated to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

You should do this instead:

```
QMyThread thread;
thread.start(...)
```

You created a pointer to a thread and did not `new` it.  I frankly see no reason for a pointer here, you can just create a normal variable and call a method on it.

If you do want a pointer, then use `std::unique_ptr` in C++11 or `boost::unique_ptr`

```
std::unique_ptr<QMyThread> thread;
thread->start(...);
```

EDIT:

You should really just create a `QThread * thread = new QThread(this);` as per the [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qthread.html).

Comment: without the pointer I'll get `error: undefined reference to `QMyThread::QMyThread()'`

Comment: @SamuelNLP have you defined all member functions, ctor/dtor properly and have you include the header in the cpp file?

Comment: @TonyTheLion `QThread` certainly does have a virtual constructor inherited from the `QObject` base class.  Qt doesn't really _force_ you to use pointers any more than you would elsewhere, i.e. if you want an object to last longer than the current scope.  It is common practice with QObjects however since Qt does a lot of automatic cleanup through the parent/child deletion mechanism.

Comment: @DanMilburn I don't really care much about a virtual constructor, as much as I care about a `virtual` destructor.

Comment: @TonyTheLion Which is of course what I meant to type, my bad.  Point is, it has one.

Answer (score 0):

How about using the `QMetaObject` class to pass the parameters to worker class. You can try like this:

`QMetaObject::invokeMethod(worker, "methodName", Q_ARG(QString, "ParameterQStringValue");`

Note this method will work if `methodName` is a slot and you use the new way of creating threads: https://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-really-truly-use-qthreads-the-full-explanation/

You can specify different parameters using `Q_ARG` macro up to 9 (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetaobject.html#details). If you need more parameters, then I suggest you to create the `QVector` with a structure and pass it to `QMetaObject::invokeMethod` as the parameter.